# Postgres text column compare mistake

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.2.24

Today I found something really confusing.

I have a table with a text column, and there are two records in the table have the save column value.

This two values have the same md5 value.

But when I use `=` operator, I can just get one value. But if I use like with `%`, I can get both values.

Is there any one who knows why?

The `erp_number` column data type is text

use like we can get two record

```
select  md5(erp_number) 
from _order 
where owner_id = 36700 
and erp_number  like  '%北京20171130DFCX'
```

returns:

```
a0630e878a08c692b0d3ddc7cf3907b4
a0630e878a08c692b0d3ddc7cf3907b4
```

with

```
like '%北京20171130DFCX' or like '北京20171130DFCX%' or like '%北京20171130DFCX'
```

I can also get the same rows. It seems it does not matter where the `%` is.

But if I use `=`, I can just get one record

```
select  erp_number 
from  _order 
where owner_id = 36700 
and erp_number  =  '北京20171130DFCX'
```

returns

```
a0630e878a08c692b0d3ddc7cf3907b4
```

Comment: `set enable_indexscan to off` and try both `like` and `=` again?.. also, post your version

Comment: on PostgreSQL9.2.15 and PostgreSQL9.2.15 i can get 0 record.

Comment: set enable_indexscan to off seems useless,nothing change

Comment: You might also need to `set enable_bitmapscan = off` to get rid of index scans.

Comment: @VaoTsun you are right , the index cause the problem, i rebuild the index and it's ok now .Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most often such effect is caused by corrupted index. YUou can check if it is so by querying with index disabled:

```
set enable_bitmapscan = off; 
set enable_indexscan to off;
```

If you see that effect disapears with "indexes disabled"
just run

```
reindex table_name;
```

Also spend some time identifying how indexes got corrupted.

thanks, Lukasz for commenting on `enable_bitmapscan`